# strange value return at times after executing stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway 
            data-source="myDataSource"
            request-channel="reqChannel" 
            reply-channel="resultChannel"
            stored-procedure-name="updateProcessStatus"
            ignore-column-meta-data="true">             
            <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="id" direction="IN"/>
            <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="status" direction="IN" type="NVARCHAR"/>
            <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="error" direction="OUT" type="NVARCHAR"/>
            <int-jdbc:parameter name="id" expression="payload.id"/>                 
            <int-jdbc:parameter name="status" expression="payload.status"/>                                                         
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>

 <int:logging-channel-adapter id="resultChannel" expression="'result receive is '+ payload " />
```

Above code is running in high concurrency environment, it seems to work fine but at times it starts logging quite weird payload return from executing stored procedure. Such as 'result received is {error=D}' ,
The Oracle SP is not coded to return value D, its suppose to be empty mostly or some error message as the case be. 
Any thoughts where this strange value may be coming from or how to go to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely something from the Oracle.

You code looks good, and that `payload.toString()` is exactly in the expected `Map` style. And you really have there `error` as an `OUT` param.

So, I don't know why you are so sure that Java is guilty.

You can switch on DEBUG login level for the `org.springframework.integration` and/or `org.springframework.jdbc` categories to scan logs on the matter for the weird behavior.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I have not seen the code that gets executed here internally, any remote chance that there is anything that could not be not be thread safe and could produce this result? The puzzle here is the stored procedure does not have any code that could return D value in error out parameter, this is quite baffling at the moment.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a thread safety vulnerability. If that was, we had a lot of problem before. Your case is a unique, so only an answer: your stored procedure. I can even suggest to change for the testing purpose the procedure code to something very simple, maybe even static and see what's going on with similar high-level load.